# Overloading Operator and vector STL problems

Tags: c++, oop, vector

I have a task: Implementing 60.000 English words from EnglishWords.txt, then Sorting it and Searching.

I have done the Sorting and Linear Search using custom MergeSort and find_if STL but when i tried to use other vector STL like upper_bound, lower_bound, binary_search it cause some problems below:

- If the lower_bound function run, it does not return the same "Index" with "searchmanually" function.
- Can not use "MatchString" (My overload operator) for lower_bound and binary_search ST or other vector STL and return C2672 and C2893 code.
- Also, can some one give me some advices on "sorting" base on alphabetical.

My full code is on https://onlinegdb.com/l4pfS9pYJ, please click on "Fork this" to edit the code.

Some additional requirements and notions.

- I'm new to OOP so show me some advices to improve my code writing skills.
- Do not use STL sort(), write your own.
- Must put all sorting, searching and working function to FastDictionary.

Below is my overload operator and the function that has problem.

```
void searchmanually(vector<Dictionary> list, string value)
{
    vector<Dictionary>::iterator it;
    it = find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), FastDictionary::MatchString(value));
    if (it != list.end())
    {
        auto idx = distance(list.begin(), it);
        cout << "Index = " << idx << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Can not find the value !." << endl;
    }
}
void binary_search_find_index(vector<Dictionary> list, string value)
{
    vector<Dictionary>::iterator it1;
    it1 = lower_bound(list.begin(), list.end(), FastDictionary::MatchString(value));
    if (it1 != list.end())
    {
        auto idx1 = distance(list.begin(), it1);
        cout << "Index = " << idx1 << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Can not find the value !." << endl;
    }
}
struct MatchString
{
private:
    const std::string& s_;
public:
    MatchString(const std::string& s) : s_(s) {}
    bool operator()(const Dictionary& obj) const
    {
        return obj._word == s_;
    }
    friend bool operator<(const Dictionary& obj, const MatchString &str) 
    {
        return obj._word < str.s_;
    }
    friend bool operator>(const Dictionary& obj, const MatchString &str)
    {
        return obj._word > str.s_;
    }
};
```

Because i think that my "errors" are kinda chained so i try to described the error as much detail as possible.

Many thanks.

Comment: First of all welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please only post one question per question. You have multiple unrelated questions.

Comment: Then regarding the searching, are you sure that the sorting works as it should? If you take a much more minimal input-set (or better yet hard-code a small set of strings) does the sorting properly handle lower- versus upper-case letters?

Comment: Also, `MatchString` saves a reference to a `std::string` object. Will the object be alive all throughout the program, when it's used in sorting and matching? Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: The ordering you're sorting into is not the same ordering that `lower_bound` expects. Check your sorting again – does it really sort alphabetically?

Comment: Also, `lower_bound` wants an ordering predicate, such as "less than", not an equality.

Answer (score 0):

**First** The **problem** is that at your given link you have named your input file incorrectly. Note carefully your input file name in the main.cpp file is **EnglishWord.txt** while your actual input file name is **EnglistWord.txt**. Note the `t` at the end of the file name.

**Second** you should replace `while (reader >> word)` with:

```
while (std::getline(reader, word))
```

as i have done in the below correct example:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Dictionary
{
public: 
    string _word;
public:
    string word() { return _word; }
    void getword(string value) { _word=value; }
    string display()
    {
        stringstream writer;
        writer << _word << " ";
        return writer.str();
    }
};
class FastDictionary : public Dictionary
{
public:
    void merge(std::vector<Dictionary>& list, int start, int middle, int end)
    {

        std::vector<Dictionary> left_vector(middle - start + 1);
        std::vector<Dictionary> right_vector(end - middle);
        for (int i = 0; i < left_vector.size(); ++i)
            left_vector[i] = list[start + i];
        for (int i = 0; i < right_vector.size(); ++i)
            right_vector[i] = list[middle + 1 + i];
        int left_value = 0, right_value = 0;
        int currentIndex = start;
        while (left_value < left_vector.size() && right_value < right_vector.size()) {
            if (left_vector[left_value]._word.size() <= right_vector[right_value]._word.size()) {
                list[currentIndex] = left_vector[left_value];
                left_value++;
            }
            else {
                list[currentIndex] = right_vector[right_value];
                right_value++;
            }
            currentIndex++;
        }
        while (left_value < left_vector.size()) list[currentIndex++] = left_vector[left_value++];
        while (right_value < right_vector.size()) list[currentIndex++] = right_vector[right_value++];
    }
    void mergeSort(std::vector<Dictionary>& list, int start, int end) {
        if (start < end) {
            int middle = (start + end) / 2;
            mergeSort(list, start, middle);
            mergeSort(list, middle + 1, end);
            merge(list, start, middle, end);
        }
    }
public:
    void searchmanually(vector<Dictionary> list, string value)
    {
        vector<Dictionary>::iterator it;
        it = find_if(list.begin(), list.end(), FastDictionary::MatchString(value));
        if (it != list.end())
        {
            auto idx = distance(list.begin(), it);
            cout << "Index = " << idx << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Can not find the value !." << endl;
        }
    }
    void binary_search_find_index(vector<Dictionary> list, string value)
    {
        vector<Dictionary>::iterator it1;
        it1 = lower_bound(list.begin(), list.end(), FastDictionary::MatchString(value));
        if (it1 != list.end())
        {
            auto idx1 = distance(list.begin(), it1);
            cout << "Index = " << idx1 << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Can not find the value !." << endl;
        }
    }
    struct MatchString
    {
    private:
        const std::string& s_;
    public:
        MatchString(const std::string& s) : s_(s) {}
        bool operator()(const Dictionary& obj) const
        {
            return obj._word == s_;
        }
        friend bool operator<(const Dictionary& obj, const MatchString &str) 
        {
            return obj._word < str.s_;
        }
        friend bool operator>(const Dictionary& obj, const MatchString &str)
        {
            return obj._word > str.s_;
        }
    };
};
    void readfile(vector<Dictionary>& list)
    {
        
        ifstream reader("EnglishWord.txt");
        string word;
        //reader.open(, ios::in);//no need for this
        if(reader)//check the state
        {
            while (std::getline(reader, word))//use getline 
            {
            
                std::cout<<word<<std::endl;
                Dictionary newList;
                newList.getword(word);
                list.push_back(newList);
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout<<"file cannot be opened"<<std::endl;
        }
        
    }
    void displayvector(vector<Dictionary>& list)
    {
        unsigned int size = list.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            cout << list[i].display();
        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        vector<Dictionary>list;
        FastDictionary fd;
        readfile(list);
        
        fd.mergeSort(list, 0, list.size() - 1);
        displayvector(list);
        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;
        fd.binary_search_find_index(list, "decidedly");
        cout << endl;
        fd.searchmanually(list, "decidedly");
        cout << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

The output of this corrected/modified example can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/6PPt1a0gi).